# Troubleshooting Conditional Form

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and trying to build a conditional form using bootstrap and JQuery. I would really appreciate the help as I've been working most of the day on this to no avail.

I'm trying to show the `div` with id `physician` (and subsequent field) when the select field with the name `AppointmentType` has a value of `Orthopedic` or `Rheumatology`. Here is the [link to the live form](https://secureform.luxsci.com/forms/17993/11228/MJip/form.html).

Here is my javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { //wait until body loads

    //Inputs that determine what fields to show
    var appttype = $('#secureform input:select[name=AppointmentType]'); 

    var physician = document.getElementById("physician");

    appttype.change(function(){ //when the Appointment Type changes
        var value=this.value;                       
        physician.addClass('hidden'); //hide everything and reveal as needed

        if (value === 'Orthopedic' || value === 'Rheumatology'){
            physician.removeClass('hidden'); //show doctors             
        }
        else {}     
    }); 

});
```

Comment: well when you mix jQuery and DOM you run into these issues.... `physician` does not have `addClass`/`removeClass` which your console should be telling you. Why? Because it is DOM and not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

These lines are going to cause errors (which you should see in your devtools console):

```
var appttype = $('#secureform input:select[name=AppointmentType]'); // `input:select` is not a valid selector and causes the rest of the script to fail

physician.addClass('hidden');   // `addClass` is a jQuery method, so this should be `$(physician).addClass('hidden')`

physician.removeClass('hidden');// `removeClass` is a jQuery method, so this should be `$(physician).removeClass('hidden')`
```

Correct those lines and it should work.

If it helps, I would write it like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
    //Inputs that determine what fields to show
    var apptType = $('#secureform select[name="AppointmentType"]'); // dropped the `input:` part
    var physician = document.getElementById('physician');

    physician.classList.add('hidden'); //hide this initially, outside the change handler

    apptType.change(function () { // when the Appointment Type changes
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();    // leave case-sensitivity out of it.
        var showables = [   // using an array as I prefer using a simple `indexOf` for multiple comparisons
            'orthopedic',
            'rheumatology',
        ];
        var isShowable = showables.indexOf(value) > -1;

        physician.classList.toggle('hidden', !isShowable);
        // or, the jQuery equivalent: 
        // $(physician).toggleClass('hidden', !isShowable);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect:

```
var appttype = $('#secureform input:select[name=AppointmentType]');
// this should be
var appttype = $('#secureform select[name=AppointmentType]');
```

Furthermore you are mixing jquery with vanilla JS. Your are using vanilla js here

```
var physician = document.getElementById("physician");
```

Physician is now a dom object and not a jquery object. You should use this instead:

```
var physician = $("#physician");
```

Additionally you should replace

```
var value=this.value;
```

with this

```
var value= $(this).val();
```